# IPv6 network addresses with 6to4 router and tunnel

Tags: ipv4, ipv6

I'm currently studying for an upcomming exam and I came across the following question, the IP-Addresses are to be filled in by me and this is my try at solving it, but I'm not sure if the IP-Address, especially for the tunnels(tun), are correct.
I'm also unsure as to what IPv6 address the client E should get, as I don't have any network address to base my IPv6-Address on.

[image]
Where C is a router that can only work with IPv4 addresses and E is a client that can only handle IPv6.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Unfortunately, all exam questions are deemed off-topic on this forum. Please see the Help Center for the type of question you may ask here.

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. NE is a site to ask and provide answers about professionally managed networks. The community has decided that certification/education questions are off topic. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details. If you have the required reptutation (currently 20+) please ask in our dedicated [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11177/) where you are free to ask a wider variety of questions.